# Это универсальное слово "конечно"

Tags: этимология

Читала впечатления иностранца от русского языка. В числе прочего он упоминает слово "конечно". Но сейчас не об этом, а о самом этот слове.
Понятно, что происходит оно от слова "конец", но не понятно, каким образом оно стало обозначать активное согласие?
*-Ты пойдешь в кино?

-Конечно!*
При чем тут вообще "конец"?

Answer (score 4):

Конечно — от прилагательного *конечный* — конечное мнение, итоговое. После него споров нет, а значит, оно бесспорно, не подвергается сомнению.
И частица, и вводное слово именно такое значение и имеют — указывают на высокую степень достоверности (само собой разумеется, никто не спорит, несомненно).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно (исконное слово, от "конъкъ" - конец) - это окончательно, потом - несомненно.

Интересно, что то же значение имело слово "натурально", "по натуре", naturlich (нем.).

Comment: "Исконное слово"- КОН, и начало и конец. 
А в остальном согласен.